# where npm native-run (in ionic cordova project) looks for $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

when I execute this command:

```
ionic cordova run android --device -l --debug --verbose
```

I get this error:

> native-run:android:utils:sdk:resolveSDKRoot Looking for $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
> native-run:android:utils:sdk:resolveSDKRoot Looking at following
> directories: [ '/home/myuser/Android/sdk' ]

It looks for `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in `/home/myuser/Android/sdk` folder, that does not exists.
Instead if I do:

```
echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

This is the result:

```
/media/myuser/Dev/Android/sdk_linux
```

So my question is why ionic/cordova are looking for `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in that directory? Where can I change the directory they look for?

Comment: have you installed Android Studio?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib yes, and I set sdk folder correctly